# html newsletter in lotus notes 8

Tags: lotus-notes, newsletter

I am trying to send HTML newsletters and it works fine in most email clients except Lotus Notes 8.

### Problem:

Table size get converted to 100% width even though set to 640. I have tried to encapsulated everything into one table. Tried the following:

```
<table width=640>
<table width="640">
<table cellpadding=5 width=640>
<table cellpadding="5" width="640">
```

Apparently Lotus Notes render it like this:

```
<table width=3D100%>
```

Of course the table has be formatted correctly like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Foobar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: StackOverflow's sister site http://doctype.com/ is a good place to ask questions like this

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS, here's a page with a list of CSS-standards and which are supported by what email-client:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Did you try applying CSS directly to the table (like `<td style="width: 640px;">`)? Some email-clients will cut and/or modify the head of HTML-mail and may therefore get rid of CSS that's defined in the `<head>` part of the mail.

Comment: You need to apply in-line CSS: it **does** work in Notes mail rendering (to a point)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this? with Lotus notes sometimes nesting helps...

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="640" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:5px";>
             Foobar apply padding as inline if you must apply padding
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```